# Check if last row status = X

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone help me figure out why this isn't working?
I have a similar script (that is working) that sends an email and then updates the latest row in a certain column to stop it issuing the email again. I took that piece of script and implemented it into the script below. However, it doesn't appear to be working...

The core of the script works (When a user subs a form, it updates the sheet and creates a new sheet based on a template with their name as the sheet name, then does an importrange to bring their data into it (URL retrieved via the form).

I need this to work on the latest row so it creates one per new form submission. The script I have taken this from works fine and is included at the bottom.

**Non-Working Script**

```
// This constant is written in column E for rows for which importrange
// has been completed.
var IMPORTED = "IMPORTED"; 

function onSubmit(e){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1UDAb8ATDChnVbi_2jktsoAfumrq0Tj8gO8xotYgb6JA") // <- Taken from other script
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]); // <- Taken from other script
  var ss = e.source;
  var Name = e.values[2];
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var col = sh.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();
  var activeRange = sh.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

   for(var i=startRow; i<data.length; i++) { // <- Taken from other script
    var row = data[i]; // <- Taken from other script
    var Training_URL = row[3];       // <- Taken from other script

  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet(1, {template: templateSheet});
  var imported = row[4] // <- Taken from other script
  if (imported != IMPORTED) { // <- Taken from other script
    newSheet.setName(Name);
    newSheet.showSheet();
    newSheet.setValue('=importrange("' + Training_URL + ',"Training!A1:I24"');
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setvalue(IMPORTED); // <- Taken from other script

  ss.getRange 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // <- Taken from other script
    }
  }
}
```

**Original Script**

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1wHojHaB8Q3g06Hc_FnsqzRTY7KAma1QEbkb4InPF2wQ");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i=startRow; i<data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1];
    var SNOW_URL = row[4];
    var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
    + "</HTML></BODY>";      
    var emailSent = row[5];
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // This part prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Your ServiceNow edit request";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I covered that off. I got there myself in the end. But thanks for taking a moment to take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get there myself in the end.
After spending an afternoon re-reading appscript, this is much tidier and safer to run. Thanks for your help everyone.

```
function onSubmit(form) {
  console.log({message: 'Form submited', form: form});
  var masterSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = masterSS.getSheetByName('Template');
  var responseSheet = masterSS.getSheetByName('Responses');
  var range = form.range;
  console.log(range.getRow());

  var newSheet = masterSS.insertSheet(1, {template: templateSheet});
  var userName = form.namedValues['Email address'][0].split('@')[0];
  newSheet.setName(userName.split('.')[0] + ' ' + userName.split('.')[1]);
  newSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue('=importrange("' + form.namedValues['URL of your sheet'][0] + '" ,"Training!A1:I24")');
  responseSheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 5).setValue('IMPORTED');
  console.log('***** All done ******');
}
```